# OnePlus 3T stuck on options menu with Power Key Damaged

Tags: boot, reboot, oneplus-3, physical-damage

i want to get it **on/Started**. But its **stuck** on the options menu. and my **power key is not working** . Is there any another way around this **Instead of me waiting** for its battery to get completely drained (which i think will mostly take **DAYs**)
[image: Photo of Options menu]Photo of Options menu where i am stuck